# ¿Cómo hacer una NpgsqlTransaction de postgres en c#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, postgresql

Tengo un proyecto en el que tengo que hacer transacción de base de datos pero no sé cómo hacerla.

Este es el código que utilizo:

```
        conexion.Open();
         NpgsqlTransaction transaccion = conexion.BeginTransaction(System.Data.IsolationLevel.Serializable); ;
        try
        {
            NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand("f_factura", conexion);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Transaction = transaccion;
            cmd.Parameters.Clear();
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@f_codigo", Convert.ToInt32(codigofactura.Text));
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@f_cliente", Convert.ToString(cliente.Text));
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@f_proveedor", Convert.ToString(proveedor.Text));
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@f_total", Convert.ToInt32(total.Text));
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            transaccion.Commit();
            MessageBox.Show("Datos guardados f ");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            transaccion.Rollback();
            MessageBox.Show("Error al guardar factura ");
        }
            conexion.Close();
```

Al ejecutar el proyecto me arroja el siguiente error:

> (System.InvalidOperationException: 'This NpgsqlTransaction has
>   completed; it is no longer usable.')

Este es mi store procedure

```
   CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_factura(
    f_codigo integer,
    f_cliente character varying,
    f_proveedor character varying,
    f_total integer
    )
    RETURNS integer AS

$BODY$
BEGIN

INSERT INTO facturacion(codigo,cliente,proveedor,total) VALUES (f_codigo,f_cliente,f_proveedor,f_total);

END
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql
```

Comment: Transaccion de base de datos

Comment: Usa [`SqlCommand`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand?view=netframework-4.8).

Comment: yo estoy utilizando es PostgreSQL

Comment: Analizando el código no veo razón para ese error. Veo que ejecutas la transacción antes de cerrar la conexion, lo que parece correcto. Es posible que este codigo esté siendo llamado varias veces?

Comment: nada, lo tengo así tal cual

Comment: Y la excepción en que línea salta? en `transaccion.Commit();`?

Comment: si, salta en  transaccion.Commit();

Comment: asegurate que los campos que le pasas lleven datos y que esos datos sean el tipo de dato esperado en tu dB

Comment: si, los datos que le mando son los mismo de la BD

Comment: pega tu store procedure en la pregunta

Comment: ya agregue mi store procedure

Comment: ahi tiene f_facturav en store procedure y tu solo tienes f_factura en C#

Comment: lo siento en es que en este me equivoque y coloque una letra de mas

Comment: Creo que `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();` ya hace un auto commit. Por eso el error en la siguiente linea.

Comment: Aún así no me funciona